# Display marks from least to high

Tags: java

I'm trying to display the marks from least to high from user input.The code gets the array of students name and array of marks.Then it has to show the output from least to high marks along with student name.I'm struck at displaying the name of student.The code just shows the marks from least to high.

```
int n = 5;//total no of students
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Students name:");
String[] s = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++)
{
  s[i] = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Enter marks:");
int array[] = new int[n]; 
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
{
 array[i] = in.nextInt();
}
Arrays.sort(array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should learn about POO to create an object holding both `mark` and `studentName`. Right now, you need to sort the arrays yourself because you need to sort two arrays at the same time based on one of them. If not, you will not be able to keep the correct mark for the student. There is no "easy" answer to this. No matter what I provide, this would be too complicated based on what I see you can do. So first, write the algorithm to sort the `array` yourself, without `Arrays.sort`. Then, simply modifiy both array at the same time.

Comment: If `s` is storing the student's names, I can't see anywhere where you are displaying `s` on the screen.

Comment: @SteveSmith `String[] s = new String[n];`

Comment: @Matthew  That doesn't write anything to the screen, that just initializes the array.

Comment: @SteveSmith Oh sorry I misread your comment, yea he's not printing the names out. The whole question is about that: *I'm struck at displaying the name of student.The code just shows the marks from least to high.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper class (say, `Student`) to store the student name and mark. Then sort them using a comparator to compare the marks.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;//total no of students
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Students name:");
        Student[] students = new Student[n];
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            students[i] = new Student();
            students[i].name = in.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter marks:");
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            students[i].mark = in.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(students, new MarkComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(students[i].name + " - "+ students[i].mark);
        }
    }
}

class Student {
    int mark;
    String name;
}

class MarkComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1,Object o2){
        Student s1=(Student)o1;
        Student s2=(Student)o2;
        if(s1.mark>=s2.mark) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter Students name:
alex
bertha
chris
dan
ervin
Enter marks:
50
40
30
20
10

ervin - 10
dan - 20
chris - 30
bertha - 40
alex - 50
```

Comment: If i get the n value from the user,it does not works correctly.If the user gives n=3,it gets only 2 input why?

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you

```
// Class student
public class Student implements Comparable {
    public String Name;
    public double Mark;

    // Should implement comparable to be able to compare it via Marks
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student per) {
        if(this.Mark == per.Mark)
            return 0;
        else
            return this.Mark > per.Mark ? 1 : -1;
    }
}


//total no of students
int n = 5;
// list of students and their marks
Student[] s = new Student[n];
// Scanner
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Get student names and their marks
for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++)
{
    s[i] = new Student();
    System.out.println("Enter Student #" + i + " name :");
    s[i].Name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Student #" + i + " mark :");
    s[i].mark = in.nextDouble();
}


Arrays.sort(s);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println(s[i].Name + " : " + s[i].Mark);
}
```